# Can Eruv Tavshilin be done for a Yom Tov rather than for shabbat?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, cooking-bishul, eruv-tavshilin

Outside of Israel, we celebrate a Yom Tov for 2 consecutive days. This year, Shavuot comes directly after Shabbat. As I understand it, on such days, one is only allowed to cook in preparation for a 24 hour period (I'm not 100% clear on the limitations of this).

My question is if we can do an Eruv Tavshilin before Shabbat or right before the Yom Tov, so that it becomes permissible to prepare food on the first day for both Yom Tov days. Is Eruv Tavshilin exclusive to Shabbat?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such leniency.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. Is this situation actually discussed in any source? I'd be interested to read about it. Also, Could you point me towards a source that explains the 24 hour rule in more detail. What are the limitations exactly? Maybe I should post another question if this hasn't been asked yet.

Comment: Basically, when it's the first day of yom tov, you can't do any preparation for the second day of yom tov or chol. And during the second day of yom tov, you can't do any preparation for chol. The same applies if chol hamoed falls after yom tov. Eruv tavshilin is an exception that allows cooking during yom tov for shabbat. The reason this is allowed is because cooking is not permitted on shabbat, so preparations _must_ be done ahead of time. Since cooking is permitted on yom tov, there is no reason for an exception to allow cooking ahead of time, since you can just do it on yom tov.

Comment: @Daniel You should make this an answer.

Comment: @Daniel That's not the entirety of it. Essentially, really prep for Shabbat is permitted on YT even without ET. ET is a rabbinic loophole in a rabbinic prohibition. See http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/563798/jewish/More-on-Eruv-Tavshilin.htm

Comment: "Simple" question. The term is called *Eruv Tavshilin* which implies the term "cooking". The idea of the Eruv is to allow cooking on Yom Tov for Shabbat. As you are not allowed to cook on Shabbat, itself, how would any type of Eruv help?

Comment: @DanF I don't understand your comment. The Eruv is trying to allow cooking on YT for next day of YT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise in your 2nd paragraph is incorrect, namely  "so that it becomes permissible to prepare food on the first day for **both** Yom Tov days".

The Eruv Tavshilin allows one to cook on Yom Tov to prepare for Shabbat only - not for another day of Yom Tov. Thus, if Yom Tov were on Thursday and Friday, followed by Shabbat, as was the case last Rosh Hashanna, one is NOT allowed to cook on Thursday to prepare for Shabbat or even for Yom Tov on Friday. Preperations for Shabbat can only be made on Friday.

Likewise for Shavuot that passed, this case is simpler. One can and should cook on Friday as it is not Yom Tov and prepare sufficient food for Shabbat and the 2 days of Shavu'ot. If needed, one can cook on Yom Tov only what is needed for that day of Yom Tov, not the next day. As you know, one is not allowed to cook on Shabbat. Thus, since Shabbat does not follow Yom Tov, there is no Eruv.

Comment: I think the OP means in that sentence if YT is Friday and Shabbat then the ET allows you to prepare from one day for the next.

Comment: @DoubleAA possibly, but the question is phrased for general cases. Either way, the Eruv is focused on cooking for Shabbat, not for another day of Yom Tov. If Shabbat & Yom Tov coincide, that's coincidental.